# applying CSS to current page link doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried every method, html & css, and javascript & css, and nothing seems to work.

this is the site I'm working on http://www.placepigalle-seattle.com/

**This is my Html:**

```
<div id="content">

        <nav  id="navlist" class="logo-center nav-overlay">
            <div class="row">
                <div medium-4 columns text-right">
                    <ul class="menu">
                        <li><a href="index.php" id="homenav">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="reserve.php" id="reservenav">Reservations</a></li>
                        <li><a href="menus.php" id="menusnav">Menus</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="medium-4 columns text-center">
                    <a href="index.php"><img alt="" src="img/logo_medium.png" class="logo medium-7"></a>
                    <a href="index.php"><img alt="" src="img/logo-dark.png" class="logo logo-dark medium-10"></a>
                </div>

                <div class=" medium-4 columns text-left">
                    <ul class="menu">
                        <li><a href="location.php" id="locationnav">Find us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="history.php" id="historynav">History</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contact.php" id="contactnav">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="nav-toggle"><i class="icon icon_menu"></i></div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

This is my CSS:

```css
body#home a#homenav,
body#contact a#contactnav,
body#gallery a#gallerynav,
body#history a#historynav,
body#location a#locationnav,
body#menus a#menusnav,
body#reserve a#reservenav, {
    background: #FFD3CEf !important;
}
```

Many thanks

Comment: You have an open tag after your first "row" div, does closing it do anything? I'm currently testing your code locally.

Comment: er, your page you linked has 2759 selectors and 15 CSS files. What is your problem exactly?

Comment: You make references to an element of id `#home` in your CSS but I do not see it in your HTML.  You need to change `body#home a#homenav` to `body a#homenav` or simply `#homenav`

Comment: Small suggestion: Don't use the `!important` keyword unless you really have to; it makes it harder to apply future specialized rule changes. Instead, get to know the rules of CSS priority and specificity (in short, the longer the CSS selector, the more CSS rules it will overwrite)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the extra markup on your CSS selectors (see my CSS sample below)

Add a missing `class` to the `div` currently shown as: `<div medium-4 columns text-right">` (see HTML fix below)

All your IDs have an extra space at the end (in the HTML) - remove them

Your background attribute needs to adjusted to `background-color: #FFD3CE;` (in you CSS)

```css
a#homenav,
a#contactnav,
a#gallerynav,
a#historynav,
a#locationnav,
a#menusnav,
a#reservenav{
    background-color: #FFD3CE;  
}
```

```html
<div id="content">

  <nav id="navlist" class="logo-center nav-overlay">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="medium-4 columns text-right">
        <ul class="menu ">
          <li><a href="index.php " id="homenav">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="reserve.php " id="reservenav">Reservations</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="menus.php " id="menusnav">Menus</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="medium-4 columns text-center">
        <a href="index.php ">
          <img alt=" " src="img/logo_medium.png" class="logo medium-7 ">
        </a>
        <a href="index.php ">
          <img alt=" " src="img/logo-dark.png" class="logo logo-dark medium-10 ">
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class=" medium-4 columns text-left ">
        <ul class="menu ">
          <li><a href="location.php " id="locationnav">Find us</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="history.php " id="historynav">History</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="contact.php " id="contactnav">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="nav-toggle "><i class="icon icon_menu "></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that the site you linked to adds the ID to the body based on the page that you are on, your css is fine (although, you have a trailing comma before the open bracket that should be removed); it's the hex code on your background color that is invalid. You have 7 characters when there should only be 6: #FFD3CEf

Generally speaking, the best way to handle special styles on the active page link is just to add a class (ex. "active") to the link that corresponds with the current page you are on, and then apply the special styles to that .active class in your css.

Comment: While it's true that the colour should be 6 characters instead of the given 7, the CSS selectors will not work (with the given HTML provided) - Did you try it?